# What is the Android vector drawable specification

Tags: android, svg, android-vectordrawable

Im attempting to replace all my `Android` drawable png assets with VectorDrawables.

Where I use the `Android Studio` standard assets obviously everything is fine.

Some externally imported SVG assets fail as Android does not support the industry-standard SVG specification.

Does an Android vector drawable specification exist?
which lists all acceptable SVG commands that Android (Android Studio) will accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I am aware, there is no formal written specification for the VectorDrawable format other than the `VectorDrawable` class definition in the documentation.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/VectorDrawable

There is also quite a lot of extra information on this page:

https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio

Neither of these have a list of SVG elements that are supported by the importer.  However you can look at the code for the importer in the Android source code for the definitive answer as to what is supported. The source code is here: [SVG2Vector.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/master/sdk-common/src/main/java/com/android/ide/common/vectordrawable/Svg2Vector.java)

From the code, you can see that the supported SVG elements are limited to:

`<polygon>`, `<rect>`, `<circle>`, `<line>`, `<path>`, `<g>`

Note that these are only partially supported, as only a limited set of their attributes are handled. Basically just the `stroke` and `fill` related ones, plus `transform` and `display:none`.

There are, however, other third-party converters available that claim to do a better job. Although what they can possibly support is limited by what VectorDrawable itself supports.